# Evaluate $\mathrm{P}(U \ge 0)$ by knowing the characteristic function of the random variable $U$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be independent random variables with characteristic function $$\phi(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}}$$

say whether the r.v. $X+Y+Z$ has a continuous density and evaluate $\mathrm{P}(X+Y+Z \ge 0)$.

Since $X$,$Y$ and $Z$ are independent we know that the characteristic function of $U =X+Y+Z$ is $$\phi_U(\theta)=\frac{1}{(1+\theta^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

which is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, so $U$ has a continuous density:

$$f(u)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}\frac{e^{-i \theta u}}{(1+\theta^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}d\theta$$

now $$\mathrm{P}(X+Y+Z \ge 0) = \int_{0}^{+ \infty} f(u)du$$

but since we can't have a solution in terms of standard functions of $f$ there is surely another way to do it, any suggestion?

Comment: *Hint.* Can you verify that $U$ has a continuous distribution that is **symmetric**?

Comment: @SangchulLee I got it! Since $\phi_U$ is a real valued function $\phi_{-U}(\theta) = \bar \phi_U(\theta) = \phi_U(\theta)$ then $U$ is symmetric and $\mathrm{P}(U \ge 0) = \frac{1}{2}$. Thank you!